# open libmigui.so failed! dlopen - dlopen failed: library "libmigui.so" not found

Tags: flutter, android-permissions

I'm building a flutter app which connects with bluetooth and then sends string data to the bluetooth. I am able to run and send the strings I have tested on many physical devices, but in POCO M2 Pro I'm getting the below issue where I issue not able to scan for nearby bluetooth devices i have enabled all the permisions as you can see in the android manifest code snippet i have shared below.

What should I do?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on POCO M2 Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
D/FlutterBluePlugin(15770): onAttachedToEngine
D/FlutterBluePlugin(15770): setup
D/FlutterBluePlugin(15770): onAttachedToActivity
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63361/SQyIhk4LoCU=/ws
Syncing files to device POCO M2 Pro...
W/BpBinder(15770): Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 263 ms,                 interface=android.app.IActivityClientController, code=24 oneway=false
D/DecorView[](15770): getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
D/DecorView[](15770): updateDecorCaptionStatus displayWindowDecor is false
D/permissions_handler(15770): No permissions found in manifest for: []3
D/permissions_handler(15770): No permissions found in manifest for: []3
E/ample.bluetoot(15770): open libmigui.so failed! dlopen - dlopen failed: library "libmigui.so"    not found
D/DecorView[](15770): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
D/DecorView[](15770): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
D/AppScoutStateMachine(15770): 15770-ScoutStateMachinecreated
D/SurfaceView(15770): UPDATE        Surface(name=SurfaceView[com.example.bluetooth/com.example.bluetooth.MainActivity])/@0x39af431,   mIsProjectionMode = false
I/OpenGLRenderer(15770): Davey! duration=111895ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=2026304,                      IntendedVsync=38487913076884, Vsync=38487913076884, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=38487913939742,    AnimationStart=38487913947867, PerformTraversalsStart=38487913950992, DrawStart=38487918510835,   FrameDeadline=38487946410216, FrameInterval=38487913905054, FrameStartTime=16666666,  SyncQueued=38487921367450, SyncStart=38487921470940, IssueDrawCommandsStart=38487922656044,  SwapBuffers=38487955776460, FrameCompleted=38599809025012, DequeueBufferDuration=6626458,  QueueBufferDuration=2227812, GpuCompleted=38599809025012, SwapBuffersCompleted=38487965035002,        DisplayPresentTime=0, 
D/DecorView[](15770): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
D/DecorView[](15770): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
D/DecorView[](15770): onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true
```

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Able to scan for nearby devices and my app should work on every device.